# permission denied to access media from storage in multi image picker

Tags: flutter

i am uploading images from gallery to app, my app ask for permission automatically but dont know what happen now it is not asking for the permission and getting error "permission denied " when i try to open gallery in the app

```
  loadGallery() async {
    List<Asset> resultImages = List<Asset>();
    try {
      resultImages = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 10,
        selectedAssets: images,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("error is : $e");
    }
    setState(() {
      images = resultImages;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file located in android/app/src/main, include these lines,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

under the "<manifest.." tag.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many scenarios that can be in the picture.

1) Maybe you have clicked on the permission for never option, where it does not asks permission later.

you have to check if you have the permission for accessing I have written the code check it just wrote an example, modify accordingly

check out the below Code for asking the permission

```
Future<bool> checkAndRequestCameraPermissions() async {
  PermissionStatus permission =
      await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
        await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]);
    return permissions[PermissionGroup.camera] == PermissionStatus.granted;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

later only check if you have permission then do the required process.

```
 if (await checkAndRequestCameraPermissions()) {
      File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      // continue with the image ...
    }
```

for time being i have used the image_picker you can use Multi Image Picker.

check out the code and let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: This is for web, right? I assume that b/c the import for `PermissionStatus` is for html.
Anyway to check permissions on ios/android?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the  version of multi image picker it will work.. if you are using latest version and still received same problem then change it to old version.